# Regular expression exclude µ from [\W_]

Tags: java, regex

I have to replace all not alphanumeric character ("_" included) and i had success with :

```
.replaceAll("[\\W_]", "%");
```

Now I need to exclude from that regex the greek char especially µ .

I had no success with "^", how can i do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: [^a-zA-Z0-9\µ] I use that it should be good

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-()/\s\p{IsGreekandCoptic}]
```